# More effecient way of calling GetStringAsync multiple times?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I have (my url list is about 1000 urls), I was wondering if there is a more effecient call multiple urls from same site (already changing the `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`).

Also is it better to reuse the same `HttpClient` or create new one on every call, below uses just one instead of multiple.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient { Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0) })
{
    var tasks = urls.Select(async url =>
    {
        await client.GetStringAsync(url).ContinueWith(response =>
        {
           var resultHtml = response.Result;
           //process the html

        });
    }).ToList();

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
```

as suggested by @cory
here is the modified code using `TPL`, however i have to set the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 100` to achieve approx same speed as the Task based, can the below code be improved?

```
var downloader = new ActionBlock<string>(async url =>
{
    var client = new WebClient();
    var resultHtml = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(new Uri(url));


}, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 100 });

foreach(var url in urls)
{
    downloader.Post(url);
}
downloader.Complete();
downloader.Completion.Wait();
```

**FINAL**

```
public void DownloadUrlContents(List<string> urls)
{
    var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var downloader = new ActionBlock<string>(async url =>
    {
        var data = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
    }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 100 });

    Parallel.ForEach(urls, (url) =>
    {
        downloader.SendAsync(url);
    });
    downloader.Complete();
    downloader.Completion.Wait();

    Console.WriteLine($"{MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name} {watch.Elapsed}");    
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend using TPL Dataflow to limit the number of tasks in flight. One thing you will find with your current implementation is that the `HttpClient` requests can actually time out, even when they haven't been sent on the network yet.

Comment: That much of paralllelism is useless if you do not have many cores on CPU, you'll just get the thread starvation. Try to use `await SendAsync` instead of `Post` to free up a thread, and do not block the tasks, use `await` all the way. HttpClient was intended to be used from a different threads, so do not create a new one each time

Comment: @VMAtm I have 6 cores on my machine, i am a bit confused, can you show me how that code would look? it seems I am going back to tasks as my first code no?

Comment: @VMAtm added final code, i think i captured it all

Comment: 1. `Parallel.ForEach` is **not** async aware. 2. You **need** to await the `SendAsync`.

Comment: @Zoinky you can use `Post`. `Post` does not block. It queues up in the action. The queue can be limited in size but is not by default.

Comment: @CoryNelson If the queue size is limited, then, if message is denied by target, it will be discarded.

Answer (score 2):

Though your code will work, it's a common practice to introduce a buffer block for your `ActionBlock`. Why to do this? First reason is task queue size, you can easily level the messages count in your queue. Second reason is that adding the message to buffer is almost instant, and after that it's `TPL Dataflow`' responsibility to handle all your items:

```
// async method here
public async Task DownloadUrlContents(List<string> urls)
{
    var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    var httpClient = new HttpClient();

    // you may limit the buffer size here
    var buffer = new BufferBlock<string>();
    var downloader = new ActionBlock<string>(async url =>
        {
            var data = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
            // handle data here
        },
        // note processot count usage here
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount });
    // notify TPL Dataflow to send messages from buffer to loader
    buffer.LinkTo(downloader, new DataflowLinkOptions {PropagateCompletion = true});

    foreach (var url in urls)
    {
        // do await here
        await buffer.SendAsync(url);
    }
    // queue is done
    buffer.Complete();

    // now it's safe to wait for completion of the downloader
    await downloader.Completion;

    Console.WriteLine($"{MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name} {watch.Elapsed}");
}
```

Comment: Your use of `BufferBlock` accomplishes nothing here. What was the intention?

Comment: @CoryNelson As I said, it's more convenient  way to use rather than limiting the `ActionBlock` `BoundedCapacilty` property. Here you're splitting the logic for *storing* the messages and *handling* them. This is better, as I think.

Comment: The `ActionBlock` already has a buffer built in -- you aren't making things better by adding another buffer in front of it. `BufferBlock` has very limited use cases, really only around non-linear dataflows that branch out.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, re-using the `HttpClient` is better, because you don't have to authenticate every single time you send a request, and you can save the state of a session using cookies, unless you initialize it with a token/cookies on every creation. Other than that, it all comes down to `ServicePoint`, where you can set the maximum allowed number of concurrent connections.

To do calls in parallel in more maintainable way, I would suggest to use the [AsyncEnumerator NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AsyncEnumerator/), which allows you to write a code like this:

```
using System.Collections.Async;

await uris.ParallelForEachAsync(
    async uri =>
    {
        var html = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri, cancellationToken);
        // process HTML
    },
    maxDegreeOfParallelism: 5,
    breakLoopOnException: false,
    cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```